# trying to reinstall python2.7 mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

So I created some issues in my python when trying to install more versions of python (2.6, 3.3) to try and get PyDev for eclipse to work.

This caused issues with my (then) working version of python 2.7

Now, I have reinstalled python 2.7. From terminal I can type `$python2.7` and get:

```
    $ python2.7
    Python 2.7.6 (v2.7.6:3a1db0d2747e, Nov 10 2013, 00:42:54) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import sys
    >>> sys.path
    ['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

To me this is a good sign.

Then, when I go to `$easy_install scipy` i get:

```
    $ easy_install scipy
    error: can't create or remove files in install directory

    The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
    installation directory:

        [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-20589.write-test'

    The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
    the distutils default setting) was:

        /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

    This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
    choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
    option).
```

So, with this, I am trying to make it back from the dark side, and get 2.7 back up and running. Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried doing what it's telling you to do and creating `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`?

Comment: who would ever do what the thing is telling them to do? seems to have worked. thanks. hopefully someone else benefits from my stupidity down the road. if you want to post an answer i will happily accept as soon as i can.

Comment: Hey, I understand. My immediate instinct when flooded with intimidating command-line error messages is to run away and call 911.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the symlink to your python installation. From the command line try:

```
sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 /Library/Python/2.7
```