# How to reinstall Mac OSX default python2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

I removed Mac OSX's default python2.7 by mistake. Can I reinstall it and IDLE without reinstalling Mac OSX? A similar question was posted in [trying to reinstall python2.7 mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593279/trying-to-reinstall-python2-7-mac), but it is not helpful for me. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution link in Chinese(https://www.zhihu.com/question/22972209). Not tried yet because I don't need to use python2.7 at the moment. Wish it to be useful for others.